# Script is not running the command I wish

Tags: bash

Wondering if anyone here can help with this problem. I have custom profiles for certain games that I wish to run but having problems.

In this example, I have a mega drive profile, and a mortal kombat profile.
Below is my runcommand-onstart.sh file. I got some of the code from someone else I found here I think, but have made changes as it didn’t work for me. The script outputs to a log for test purposes. The text output to the log is correct, but doesn’t do what it should, see below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get system name
system=$1
emulator=$2
rom=$3
command=$4

# rom_bn receives $rom excluding everything from the first char to the last slash '/'
rom_bn="${rom##*/}"

# rom_bn receives $rom_bn excluding everything from the last char to the first dot '.'
rom_bn="${rom_bn%.*}"

rom_joined='"'$rom_bn'"'

# Write to Runcommand Log to test
echo emitter LoadProfileByEmulator "$rom_joined" $1 >> $HOME/start.log

emitter LoadProfileByEmulator "$rom_joined" $1
```

The command I wish to run is:
emitter LoadProfileByEmulator "Mortal Kombat (World)" megadrive

The test log has the following line:
emitter LoadProfileByEmulator "Mortal Kombat (World)" megadrive

But ledspicer loads the megadrive profile… like it can't read the "Mortal Kombat" bit.
If I copy and paste that line from the log into terminal, ledspicer loads the Mortal Kombat profile as it should….

Many thanks for any help

Comment: You don't need the literal double quotes in `rom_joined`. Just quoting the variable in the command is sufficient.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes aren't processed in the expansion of variables, so when you add quotes to `$rom_joined`, those are being treated literally. But since the profile doesn't actually have quotes in its name, that doesn't work.

Just quoting the variable in the argument to `emitter` is enough to make it a single word. If you want the quotes in the log, do that in the `echo` command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get system name
system=$1
emulator=$2
rom=$3
command=$4

# rom_bn receives $rom excluding everything from the first char to the last slash '/'
rom_bn="${rom##*/}"

# rom_bn receives $rom_bn excluding everything from the last char to the first dot '.'
rom_bn="${rom_bn%.*}"


# Write to Runcommand Log to test
echo "emitter LoadProfileByEmulator '$rom_joined' '$system'" >> $HOME/start.log

emitter LoadProfileByEmulator "$rom_bn" "$system"
```